# Does java has default implementation to restore original object state?

Tags: java

Basically, I want to reset object to the default state. 
I think about the following:

```
// first declaration
Object a = new Object();
/* 
some job over object
*/
//assign a new object to reset it
a= new Object();
```

Another idea is to create method inside object class, which will set the desired values, so

```
a.reset();
```

Is there some default way to do that or does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Put your constructor logic in a method, so your constructor only calls this method. Make such method public.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some default way to do that

Nope. It's relatively tricky, because presumably you'd want to do it transitively - but that could cause problems if you have a *different* object which refers to some of the same objects, and you don't want to reset that:

```
Date d = ...;
Foo x = new Foo();
Foo y = new Foo();
x.setDate(d);
y.setDate(d);
d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000L);
x.reset();
```

What should that do in terms of the `Date` referred to within the two `Foo` objects?

This needs to be considered on a case-by-case basis, and the more immutability you can use, the better - but there's nothing provided by default, no.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the `a.reset()` method is the best.

You can't expect the compiler to know to what state you want the object to be restored, unless you tell it so.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting an object can cause problems if you keep a reference elsewhere.

```
Foo a=new Foo();
a.something();
Foo b=a;
a.reset();
//b is now reset!
```

You can simple say `a=new Foo()` (or object, etc), and the old object is disposed if not referenced strongly elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a real copy of your object (using a copy constructor) with the state you want to restore:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo(a); // b contains the state you want to restore
a.something();      // a is modified
a = b;              // the state of a is restored by b
```