# Java ReentrantLock (try/finally)— object in a damaged state in the "try" code block before an exception is thrown

Tags: java, concurrency

I am reading the concurrent chapter of *Core Java Volume I*.And read something as followed:

"Be careful to ensure that the code in a critical section is not bypassed by
throwing an exception. If an exception is thrown before the end of the
section,the finally clause will relinquish the lock, **but the object may
be in a damaged state**."

So I wonder how to deal with that problem if the object is in a damaged state.Take the following code for example,in my opinion, I think something should be done to recover the Object o to what it was before.Is that right？

```java
var myLock = new ReetrantLock();
...
myLock.lock();
try{

  Object o  = getObject();//A reference to a shared variable O is read from main memory. 
                          //Changes to O will directly change the data in main memory.
  o.doSomeThingA(); // execution succeeded. O has been changed
  o.doSomeThingB(); // throw exception
  o.doSomeThingC();

}finally{
  myLock.unLock(); 
}
```

I am really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should restore the state before unlock is called, you can do something similar to that

```
var myLock = new ReetrantLock();
...
myLock.lock();
try {

  Object o = getObject();//A reference to a shared variable O is read from main memory. 
                         //Changes to O will directly change the data in main memory.
  o.doSomeThingA();      // execution succeeded. O has been changed
  o.doSomeThingB();      // throw exception
  o.doSomeThingC();
} catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: Restore data as they were before the try
} finally {
  myLock.unLock(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have searched if java has default method to restore data of an object but not found.here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569580/does-java-has-default-implementation-to-restore-original-object-state Is it convinent for you to tell me more in details?thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to make a deep copy of all values of this object and then if somthing goes wrong do the deep copy in the other direction

Comment: I see.I will supplement the relevant knowledge.Thanks !